# Spring Kafka is unable to Serialize the object

Tags: serialization, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am placing an object on the Kafka queue.
Getting this error when placing an object on Kafka

10:40:51,823 ERROR [org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler] (scheduling-1) Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't convert value of class com.tlx.afxintegrations.commons.models.request.TransactionalJournalRequestDto to class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer specified in value.serializer
at deployment.afx-integrations.war//org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:957)
at deployment.afx-integrations.war//org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:914)
at deployment.afx-integrations.war//org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.send(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:993)
at deployment.afx-integrations.war//org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:655)
at deployment.afx-integrations.war//org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:403)
at deployment.afx-integrations.war//com.tlx.afxintegrations.inbound.accountingentries.listeners.FCYTransactionsListener.listenForFCYTransactions(FCYTransactionsListener.java:149)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor90.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at deployment.afx-integrations.war//org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
at deployment.afx-integrations.war//org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.tlx.afxintegrations.commons.models.request.TransactionalJournalRequestDto cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (com.tlx.afxintegrations.commons.models.request.TransactionalJournalRequestDto is in unnamed module of loader 'deployment.afx-integrations.war' @155f826; java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
at deployment.afx-integrations.war//org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer.serialize(StringSerializer.java:29)
at deployment.afx-integrations.war//org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:62)
at deployment.afx-integrations.war//org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:954)
... 16 more

We are placing an object in the Kafka queue.

Expecting this to be serialized.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you use a default Spring Boot auto-configuration which provides a `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer` for the `value.serializer` property by default:

```
    /**
     * Serializer class for values.
     */
    private Class<?> valueSerializer = StringSerializer.class;
```

Since you don't send a `String` from your application, it is not a surprise that your `com.tlx.afxintegrations.commons.models.request.TransactionalJournalRequestDto` cannot be serialized for the Kafka record.

Consider to configure that `spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer` Spring Boot property to whatever fits into serialization logic for your `TransactionalJournalRequestDto`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#messaging.kafka.additional-properties

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/serdes.html